# Save folder configurations for each folder?

Tags: nautilus, mate, caja

Is there any way to save folder configurations like icon size or to change to list view for each individual folder?
By the way I'm using Ubuntu Mate and it comes with Caja but this suppose to be Nautilus fork.

Regular Home Folder:
[image: Regular Home Folder]

Pictures Folder:
[image: Pictures Folder]

Comment: I want know too